# Gemfile with exact versions vs Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile, gemfile.lock

Is there any difference between specifying exact versions of third-party libraries in `Gemfile` and using `Gemfile.lock`?

If I use exact versions in `Gemfile` will it be the same as distributing `Gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, an exactly specified `Gemfile` and using a `Gemfile.lock` is not the same.

Your `Gemfile` might include all gems you are using with a specific version. But the `Gemfile.lock` will also include all gems that are dependencies of the gem you use. That means that a typical `Gemfile.lock` will include way more gems when a `Gemfile`.

Furthermore: You might have gems or gem versions to your `Gemfile` that are incompatible with each other. A `Gemfile.lock` is generated by bundler and represents a set of gem versions that are compatible with each other. If bundler is not able to fulfill all required dependencies then it will not generate a `Gemfile.lock`.

That said: Pin only versions in your `Gemfile` that you need to pin because of version requirements of your app. Let bundler find a valid combination and check that `Gemfile.lock` into version control system.

Answer (score 0):

if I rename Gemfile.lock into Gemfile, `bundle install` fails with syntax error.